# Android instrumentation tests using multiple emulators

Tags: android, testing, wear-os, instrumentation, android-espresso

I have an Android and Android Wear app that I would like to test end-to-end in a automated real life scenario. I want to run two emulators, one with Android app and second with the Wear app. Probably by using Espresso framework to control each device and check if they're syncing their data properly. Optimistically I would like to plug into already existing Instrumentation Testing framework, to have nice integration with Android Studio.
Is that even possible? I couldn't find anything in documentation nor by searching the web.

I see no other way to test that my services and multi-threaded connections are actually doing what they're supposed to. Maybe there's a better way?